# Getting data from form.serializaArray()

Tags: javascript, php

i need help..why does my code not working?what is the proper way to get the data from a `form.serialize`? mines not working.. also am doing it right when passing it to php? also my php code looks awful and does not look like a good oop

***html***

```
 <form action="" name="frm" id="frm" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="title_val" value="" id="title_val"/>
            <a href="javascript:;" title="" id="save">post topic</a> 
        </form>
        <div id="test">
        </div>
```

***Javascript***

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#save').click(function() {
            var form = $('#frm');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'topic.php',
                type:'get',
                data: form.serializeArray(),
                success: function(response) {  
                   $('#test').html(response);
                }
            }); 
        }); 

    });
```

***Php***

```
<?php
    class test{

        public function test2($val){
            return $val;
        }
    }

    $test = new test();
    echo $test->test2($_POST['title_val']); 

?>
```

*OUTPUT*

[image]

Comment: What does var_dump($_GET); returns in your php? Also, why are you using GET? What does console.log(frm.serializeArray) return)

Comment: i have added the output..don't know why its an error

Comment: im trying  to learn form.serializeArray()

Comment: Also, you have to unserialize data in PHP.

Comment: Thanks but how do i do that?

Comment: Manual: http://us3.php.net/unserialize

Comment: what happens if i don't unserialize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're telling your ajax call to send the variables as `GET` variables, then trying to access them with the `$_POST` hyperglobal. Change `GET` to `POST`:

```
type:'post',
```

Also, it should be noted that you are binding your ajax call to the **click** on your submit button, so your form will still be posting. You should bind on the form's **submit** function instead and use `preventDefault` to prevent the form posting.

```
$('#frm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop form processing normally
    $.ajax({
        url: 'topic.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: $(this).serializeArray(),
        success: function(response) {  
            $('#test').html(response);
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: ooh.. been looking for the php problem since yesterday.then the mistake was on javascript... -_-..

Comment: well.Thanks @scrowler..:)..so is my php fine?

Comment: That depends on whether you want to use `POST` or `GET` - I'd recommend `POST` so your variables stay out of the query string. In your case, your PHP is fine - you'll probably need to `unserialize` your data though: http://us3.php.net/unserialize